# Libtorrent settings for slow disk

Tags: libtorrent

It seems libtorrent performs well when you have a fast disk but the performance is sluggy on slower disk. Here I've added a log of Ubuntu download on a flash drive with a write speed of 3,2MB/s. As you can see the download speed gradually reduces to zero. I've limited the connection limit to 10 but not setting the connection limit also does not make much difference other than starting at 10 MB/s. My suspicion is that disk is not able to keep up with the available download speed and back pressure is causing a reduction on later download speed.

```
ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso: 0.00% complete (down: 0.0 kB/s up: 0.0 kB/s peers: 0) checking_resume_data
ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso: 0.19% complete (down: 777.0 kB/s up: 25.0 kB/s peers: 10) downloading
ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso: 0.60% complete (down: 1365.0 kB/s up: 42.0 kB/s peers: 10) downloading
ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso: 1.22% complete (down: 2142.0 kB/s up: 63.0 kB/s peers: 10) downloading
ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso: 1.67% complete (down: 2240.0 kB/s up: 65.0 kB/s peers: 10) downloading
ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso: 2.29% complete (down: 2116.0 kB/s up: 61.0 kB/s peers: 10) downloading
ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso: 2.85% complete (down: 1954.0 kB/s up: 56.0 kB/s peers: 10) downloading
ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso: 3.33% complete (down: 1931.0 kB/s up: 55.0 kB/s peers: 10) downloading
ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso: 3.44% complete (down: 932.0 kB/s up: 26.0 kB/s peers: 10) downloading
ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso: 3.44% complete (down: 305.0 kB/s up: 8.0 kB/s peers: 10) downloading
ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso: 3.44% complete (down: 100.0 kB/s up: 2.0 kB/s peers: 10) downloading
ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso: 3.44% complete (down: 32.0 kB/s up: 0.0 kB/s peers: 10) downloading
ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso: 3.44% complete (down: 10.0 kB/s up: 0.0 kB/s peers: 10) downloading
ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso: 3.44% complete (down: 3.0 kB/s up: 0.0 kB/s peers: 10) downloading
ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso: 3.44% complete (down: 1.0 kB/s up: 0.0 kB/s peers: 10) downloading
ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso: 3.44% complete (down: 0.0 kB/s up: 0.0 kB/s peers: 10) downloading
ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso: 3.44% complete (down: 0.0 kB/s up: 0.0 kB/s peers: 10) downloading
ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso: 3.44% complete (down: 0.0 kB/s up: 0.0 kB/s peers: 10) downloading
ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso: 3.44% complete (down: 0.0 kB/s up: 0.0 kB/s peers: 10) downloading
```

How can I optimize my libtorrent settings to have a decent speed on my flash drive? Any suggestions?

Comment: my suspicion would be that it's not primarily slow media that's the problem, but a filesystem that does not support sparse files. Are you running FAT32 by any chance? Have you tried a newer filesystem?

Comment: @Arvid yes, you're right. I'm using FAT32. I tested with NTFS and the speed was much higher. Is there any libtorrent setting I can set so that I'll still have a decent download speed on FAT32?

Answer (score 1):

Your performance issue appears to be caused by the lack of support for sparse files on your filesystem. By default, libtorrent will download pieces of the files in "random" order, expecting the filesystem to handle that well. Most modern filesystems do pretty well.

If you're using FAT however, the operating system will extend and allocate space for every byte up to the point where a piece is written, which may be several gigabytes. This will cause the download to stall until the file is allocated.

A simple way to mitigate some of this effect is to enable sequential download mode for the torrent. This disables the rarest-first piece picking mechanism, which reduces overall swarm performance (if every peer in a swarm does this, it would not handle spikes in demand very well).

see [set_sequential_download()](https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent/issues/3382).

Also see this recent [ticket](https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent/issues/3382) on this topic.